# Is there any option to see my JMeter reports in JIRA?

Tags: jmeter, jira

Finished my performance test and need to make visible those test reports in my JIRA cases. Is there any efficient way to verify my JMeter test results in JIRA ?
Please add some screenshots for my reference if there is any methods to be followed to achieve this requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware JIRA has a set of [REST APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis) and looking into [How to add an attachment to a JIRA issue using REST API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-a-jira-issue-using-rest-api-699957734.html) article you should be able to upload JMeter test result into JIRA using the following command:

```
curl -D- -u {username}:{password} -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@{path/to/file}" http://{base-url}/rest/api/2/issue/{issue-key}/attachments
```

---

You can upload results file even from JMeter test itself, i.e.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```
2. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
3. Add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to the tear Down Thread Group and put your JIRA credentials there

   [image: JIRA Authr Manager]
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send `X-Atlassian-Token` header with the value of `nocheck`

   [image: JMeter HTTP Header Manager]
5. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it as follows:

   - Protocol: your JIRA installation protocol, most likely `https`
   - Host: your JIRA installation IP address or hostname
   - Method: `POST`
   - Path: `/rest/api/2/issue/issue-key/attachments`
   - Tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box
   - In the "File Upload" tab provide full or relative path to your .jtl results file and its MIME type. Keep "Parameter Name" value as `file`

     [image: JMeter JIRA Upload File]

See [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more information on performing file uploads using JMeter.

Comment: You are using wrong URL, you should be sending your request to `/rest/api/2/issue/issue-key/attachments`, not to `/browse/issue-key`